# How do I reshape pytorch tensor from [a, b*c] to [b,a,c]?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, conv-neural-network

I'm getting this code error, and I am unsure on how to reshape my tensor.

```
RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [32, 35, 2], but got 2-dimensional input of size [35, 64] instead
```

Comment: what's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reshape` function from torch as follows:

```
a = torch.rand((35,64))
b = torch.reshape(a, (32,35,2))
```